# Angular UI Bootstrap Popover w/HTML not functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the snippet below in my HTML:

```
<a ng-href="#" popover popover-template="views/popovers/cu.html" popover-trigger="click" popover-placement="top">
  <img ng-src="{{chat.avatar}}" width="50" height="40">
</a>
```

Clicking the `a` tag does not trigger the popover.  Popover's in my application work without HTML, but not with.

I've essentially copied the "Popover with Template" section from the docs here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

But it still does not function as it does in the example above.

What's wrong?

Comment: you don't need the ``popover`` attribute when you have the ``popover-template`` attribute, also ``ng-href="#"`` isn't necessary

Comment: No difference.  It wasn't working even before I added it.

Comment: Does it work when you remove ``ng-href="#"``  ?

Comment: No, and it doesn't have cursor of pointer when I remove it.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? is the templateUrl available?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're wrapping this `a` element inside another element  with a `ng-controller` atribute?

Comment: Yes, I have a controller for it.

Comment: No error in console from this.

Comment: what's inside cu.html?

Comment: Some markup, the same markup from the link in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Assuming that you're not using the script tag, and you're using a separate html file, add an extra single quote in your popover-template. See my example on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YsK6mHvj891EilZAJ1oj?p=preview). So that should be `popover-template="'cu.html'"` instead of `popover-template="cu.html"`.

```
<a ng-href="#" popover-template="'cu.html'" popover-trigger="click" popover-placement="top" >
  <img ng-src="{{chat.avatar}}" width="50" height="50">
</a>
```

---

Edit: Another way to achieve this is using the script tag and having 'text/ng-template' as the type. The id would be the text that you place inside the `popover-template`. Take a look at this version on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PwHTFEXINKxpdJQfvZRm?p=preview).

So I would look this:

```
<a ng-href="#" popover-template="'cu.html'" popover-trigger="click" popover-placement="top">
  <img ng-src="{{chat.avatar}}" width="50" height="50">
</a>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="cu.html">
    <div>
      Hey there!
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Added an alternative. Please see the edited version of my answer.

Comment: That didn't do it either.  I'm thinking maybe it's something else in my Angular app causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path in `popover-template`?